# A question about the convergence of an integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I've a positive continuous function : 
$$q : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}.$$

Assuming that the function $ t \mapsto t\cdot q(t) $ can be integrated (i.e.

$ \int_0^{x}{t\cdot q(t)dt}$ converges when $x$ tends to infinity).

I want to show that $x \mapsto \int_x^{\infty}{q(t)dt}$ can be integrated on $\mathbb{R^+}$.

Any ideas?

I already derived :  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{x\cdot\int_x^{\infty}{q(t)dt}} = 0.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the key idea would be noting the exchange of integrals
$$
\int_0^\infty \bigg( \int_x^\infty q(t) \, dt \bigg)\, dx = \int_0^\infty \bigg( \int_0^t dx \bigg) q(t)\,dt.
$$
This is valid since the integrand is nonnegative (Tonelli's theorem).

To be more precise, consider the function
$$
Q(t,x) = \begin{cases}
q(t), &\text{if }t>x, \\ 0, &\text{if } t\le x.
\end{cases}
$$
Then each side of the above equation equals $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty Q(t,x) \,dt \,dx$, and the use of Tonelli's theorem becomes easier to see.

Comment: Hey, thank for your answer. I don't understand how you can apply the Tonelli's theorem here, because the domain of integration of the second integral $[x, \infty]$ depends on the free variable x. Can you be more explicit ?

Comment: @Adri That's a fair question - see edits above.

Comment: Thank you, it is now clear :). (but I can't use your proof because I know only a restrictive -and stupid- version of the Tonelli's theorem where the function have to be continuous...)

Comment: That's annoying :) You could try, in the definition of $Q$, replacing the $0$ with $\frac32-\frac x{2t}$ when $\frac x3<t\le x$ (and leaving it $0$ when $t\le \frac x3$); now $Q$ is continuous. That choice makes the right-hand side of the first equation equal to $\int_0^\infty 2tq(t)\,dt$, which you're assuming converges. And I think it only increases the left-hand side, so the fact that the increased function is integrable implies that $\int_x^\infty q(t)\,dt$ is also integrable.

Comment: Haha, good hack, thank :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this proof to be simple: 
$$\int_0^a{\int_x^{\infty}{q(t)dt}} = [x\int_x^\infty{q(t)dt}]_0^a + \int_0^a{xq(x)dx} $$
And since : 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{x\cdot\int_x^{\infty}{q(t)dt}} = 0$$
We have the result.

I think it works but it's not as quick as Greg Martin's proof.